# Read data from Firebase and add them to scope

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

For a RSS application, I want to read an array of JSON objects (each representing the parameters of an individual feed) from Firebase.

Without Firebase, the application works, based on the declaration

```
$scope.rssSourcesTest = [
    {'aid': 'urlaub99euro', 'atitle': 'Urlaub99Euro', 'aurl': 'http://www.urlaub99euro.de/rss3b/', 'atags': 'deutschland'},
    {'aid': 'urlaub_fm', 'atitle': 'urlaub.fm', 'aurl': 'http://urlaub.fm/rss/', 'atags': ''}
    ];
```

Writing $scope.rssSourcesTest into Firebase works. Reading the array back also works, but I cannot assign the resulting array rssSources2 to a scope variable such as $scope.rssSources2.

I read here a lot of articles on this, the solution might involce $timeout or $apply(). Here is the test.

```
        // Test Read rssSources from Firebase ************************

    // Test Array
    $scope.rssSourcesTest = [
    {'aid': 'urlaub99euro', 'atitle': 'Urlaub99Euro', 'aurl': 'http://www.urlaub99euro.de/rss3b/', 'atags': 'deutschland'},
    {'aid': 'urlaub_fm', 'atitle': 'urlaub.fm', 'aurl': 'http://urlaub.fm/rss/', 'atags': ''}
    ];
    // console.log($scope.rssSourcesTest[0].aid);
    // works!

    // write
    var sourcesFB = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxx.com/sourcestest");
    sourcesFB.set($scope.rssSources);
    // works

    // read
    var rssSourcesRef = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxx.com/sourcestest/");
    rssSourcesRef.on('value', function(snap) {
            rssSources2 = snap.val();
            console.log("read from FB data ..: " + rssSources2[0].aid);
            // works
    });
    console.log($scope.rssSources2[0].aid);
    // is $scope.rssSources2 is undefined

    // /Test Read rssSources from Firebase ************************
```

Answer (score 1):

$scope.rssSources2 and rssSources2 are two different variables. Replace:

```
rssSources2 = snap.val();
```

with:

```
$scope.rssSources2 = snap.val();
```

Comment: Partially correct. One still needs to use $timeout or $scope.$digest() to invoke dirty checking and compiler, otherwise changes will not be displayed until the next digest event.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer (this was clear, though) and the comment. $timeout did not work for some reason, it threw an error with undefined in console.log.

Inserting the $scope.$digest(); line solved the whole problem - thanks Kato.

      var rssSourcesRef = new Firebase("https://xxxxxx.com/sources/");
  rssSourcesRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
   // $timeout(function() {
    $scope.rssSources = snapshot.val();
   // })
    $scope.$digest();
    console.log("read from FB data ..: " + $scope.rssSources[1].aid);
    // works
  });